# comparing filenames with .bat and writing missing entries into .txt

Tags: batch-file, compare, filenames

i want to compare some files in a folder and then write missing ones into a text file.

i've got a folder

> c:\sessions\

with files in it. those files are looking like:

```
Blabla-1111-FOO
Blabla-1111-BAR1
Bleble-2222-FOO
Bleble-2222-BAR1
Bleble-2222-BAR2
Bleble-2222-BAR3
Bleble-2222-BAR4
Blublu-5678-FOO
Blublu-5678-BAR1
Blublu-5678-BAR2
Blublu-5678-BAR3
Blublu-5678-BAR4
Blublu-5678-BAR5
Bleble-6666-FOO
Bloblo-7777-FOO
Bloblo-8888-FOO
Bloblo-9999-FOO
```

i need a .bat file which writes down all files ending with -FOO where no matching -BAR exists into a noBARs.txt. So in this case the noBARs.txt should look like this:

```
Bleble-6666-FOO
Bloblo-7777-FOO
Bloblo-8888-FOO
Bloblo-9999-FOO
```

There can be multiple -BAR files that belong to one -FOO file.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
@echo off
    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=c:\sessions"
set "output=noBARs.txt"
set "find=*foo"
set "repl=bar*"

1>"%output%" (
  for %%e in ("%source%\%find%") do (
    set "file=%%e"
    if not exist "!file:~0,-3!%repl%" (
      echo %%~ne
    )
  )
)
```

This will iterate through all the files that contain `*foo` within their filename.  Then it replaces the last 3 characters of the filename with `bar*` and checks for the existence of the file. If the corresponding `bar` file doesn't exist it will write the original filename to the output file `noBARs.txt`.

---

I've added an alternative version of the script based on the last comment of dEEkAy in which he states that files ending with `FOO` followed by a numerical constant should be tested as well. I'm still quite uncertain what the exact intention of dEEkAy is but I'm assuming that the file names `*FOO*` should be handled the same as `*FOO`.

The following input:

```
Blabla-1111-FOO
Blabla-1111-BAR1
Bleble-2222-FOO
Bleble-2222-BAR1
Bleble-2222-BAR5
Blublu-3333-FOO6
Blublu-3333-BAR1
Blublu-5678-FOO
Blublu-5678-FOO1
Blublu-5678-BAR2
Blublu-5678-BAR4
Bleble-6666-FOO
Bloblo-7777-FOO5
Bloblo-7777-BAR8
Bloblo-9999-FOO
Blublu-9999-FOO9
Bloblo-!^^!-FOO
```

Will produce the following output:

```
Bleble-6666-FOO
Bloblo-!^^!-FOO
Bloblo-9999-FOO
Blublu-9999-FOO9
```

The alternative version of the script is also more robust than the original. It should now be capable of handling file names and paths that contain exclamation marks and carets appropriately. Unfortunately, it does come with a cost. Due to the `call` command which will be executed for each iteration of the for-loop, the script has become a lot slower. Perhaps someone with more batch-file scripting experience can come up with a better solution.

```
@echo off

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "source=c:\sessions"
set "output=noBARs.txt"
set "find=foo"
set "repl=bar"

1>"%output%" (
  for %%e in ("%source%\*%find%*") do (
    set "path=%%~dpe"
    set "file=%%~ne"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call :ReplaceEndOfString file match "%find%" "%repl%"

    if not exist "!path!!match!*" (
      echo !file!
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
exit /b

:ReplaceEndOfString (__in *source, __out *dest, __in find, __in repl) {
  set "temp=!%1:*%~3=%~3!"
  set "%2=!%1:%temp%=%~4!"
  exit /b
}
```

Keep in mind that `"%source%\*%find%*"` will match any file that contains `%find%` within its file name, whereas `"%source%\*%find%?"` only matches file names that end with `%find%` including one optional character that could be anything.

---

I just happened to need some code similar to this and decided to take another look. The main bottleneck of the code seems to be the invocation of the `call` command. While I don't see a way around this (other than using macros), the execution time of the `call` command can be greatly improved (with a factor of 2, roughly).

Calling a function by its label seems to be a lot slower than calling the `set` command. I'm not entirely sure but I can remember something about calling labels being slow due to requiring a rescan of the entire script file. Carets and exclamation marks within file names also appear to remain intact because the delayed expansion phase seems to occur before the `set` command is called.

```
@echo off

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "source=c:\sessions"
set "output=nobars.txt"
set "find=foo"
set "repl=bar"

1>"%output%" (
  for %%e in ("%source%\*%find%*") do (
    set "path=%%~dpe"
    set "file=%%~ne"

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "end=!file:*%find%=%find%!"
    call set "match=%%file:!end!=%repl%%%"

    if not exist "!path!!match!*" (
      echo !file!
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. You saved me a lot of hassle. Your solution works perfectly. I only had to change that part next to -3!%match% to -4 cause in my actual problem, i got somewhat different names.

is there a way to overwrite the output file instead of appending each time i run this batch?

Comment: seems like i cannot edit my comment anymore. i fixed that appending issue by deleting the file via del ...txt

Comment: @dEEkAy I have changed the script accordingly. Each time it is run, the output file will be overwritten. It will also be a lot faster in case the source directory contains lots of files. Please feel free to mark my post as the answer if it has helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: Your new version produces a textfile with full path and filenames. i'll stick to the first one where i delete the file before entering the for-block. This does the trick pretty well.

Is it possible to put in a variable/parameter for the foo part? right now your solution just replaces the last part of the file foo with bar and checks.

In my actual problem, sometimes i have foo1, foo2 and this produces issues. Especially if TestTest-1234-foo1 and -foo2 have matching files with -bar, it still prints out those as if they had no corresponding -bar files.

Comment: @dEEkAy Both versions of the script use the command `echo %%~ne` to print the names of the FOO files. The `~n` part of the for-loop variable `%e` specifies that only the file name and not the full path should be used. I don't understand how this could be different all of a sudden. Another thing I don't understand is how a file called `TestTest-1234-FOO1` could even be printed at all. Only files that end with `*foo` are being iterated, not `*foo*` or `*foo?`. Concerning the other condition you've mentioned, could you update your post with a new list of input and expected output?

Comment: sorry for being THIS LATE. your solution worked perfectly, i just messed something up =). Thank you for your help treintje